# Type parameter T is not within its bound; should extend MyBaseClass

Tags: java, generics, interface

I'm dealing with some legacy code, trying to refactor and extract common code. I've ended up with the following hierarchy.

```
public interface MyInterface<T extends MyBaseClass> {...}
public class MyBaseClass {...}
public class MyClass extends MyBaseClass implements MyOtherInterface<MyClass> {...}

public interface MyOtherInterface<T extends MyOtherInterface<T>> {
    void func(MyInterface<T> context);  // Complains that T should extend MyBaseClass
}
```

In words, I want to specify that the parameter T passed to MyOtherInterface should be a class that extends MyBaseClass and implements MyOtherInterface. Something like this:

```
public interface MyOtherInterface<T extends MyOtherInterface<T extends MyBaseClass>>
```

How can I do this? I am trying to change as little as possible. I am not sure the above is possible and I might have to actually flip the hierarchy.

Comment: public interface MyOtherInterface<T extends MyClass>

Comment: @Zeromus, a super class (or interface) shouldn't know about the base classes, that's bad design. The actual OPs design is probably an example of XY problem. Your usecase may be achieved using another design if you let us know what you want to solve instead of how you want to solve it.

Comment: How about: `MyOtherInterface<T extends MyBaseClass & MyOtherInterface<T>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle's Java tutorial:

```
Multiple Bounds

The preceding example illustrates the use of a type parameter with a single bound, but a type parameter can have multiple bounds:

<T extends B1 & B2 & B3> A type variable with multiple bounds is a subtype of all the types listed in the bound. If one of the bounds is a class, it must be specified first. For example:

Class A { /* ... */ } interface B { /* ... */ } interface C { /* ...
*/ }

class D <T extends A & B & C> { /* ... */ } If bound A is not specified first, you get a compile-time error:

class D <T extends B & A & C> { /* ... */ }  // compile-time error
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html